# Who are the 'sons of God referred to in Job 38:7?

Tags: job, terminology

In Job 1 and 2 we find the term 'sons of God' and then again in 38:7.

> When the morning stars sang together And all the sons of God shouted for joy?

Who are these 'sons of God' that were clearly witnesses of the creation of this planet (in the context of 38:4-6)?

> Where were you when I laid the foundation of the earth? Tell Me, if you have understanding, Who set its measurements? Since you know. Or who stretched the measuring line over it? “On what were its bases sunk? Or who laid its cornerstone?

I am not asking who the morning stars are as another question on this site does.

Comment: It is appreciated if you include the verse quote in the question.

Comment: This topic has been analyzed yet in the answer (post) # 706.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is reasonable to conclude that it refers to angels, just as at the beginning of the book of Job which mentions Satan among other
among the sons of the God. In the Jewish tradition they clearly refers to angels. (Niv e 'angels', ASV sons 'of God' hebr. bə·nê hā·’ĕ·lō·hîm). It’s hard to imagine who else it would refer to.

Of course, it could be argued that it refers to a pre-monotheistic religion in which Yahweh is seen as the supremacy and the gods of the Gentiles (?) As his sons. However, this does not fit the concept of the book of Job (or the context of the verse you mention, actually its not dealing about that). There is no reference to this belief anywhere.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: www. biblehub.com should be good.